# Find string values in list and replace them

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a list full of floats, ints and strings mixed in unknown order. I want to find all string values and replace them with 0. Problem is that i dont know what will this string look like except that it will contain 4 characters (hex number).

So for example i will have such a list:

`h = [1, 2, 5.3, '00cc', 3.2, '085d']`

And I want to replace those strings (in this example '00cc' and '085d') with zeros so that my final list will look like:

`h = [1, 2, 5.3, 0, 3.2, 0]`

I know the ways to find string or value in list and replace it but not in case when I know only type and length of list element.

Comment: `[ x if type(x) is not str else 0 for x in h ]`

Comment: `[0 if type(i) is str else i for i in h]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this by [List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
[0 if type(i) is str else i for i in h]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
h = [1, 2, 5.3, '00cc', 3.2, '085d']
for i, x in enumerate(h):
    if type(x) == str:
        h[i]=0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for X in xrange(0,len(h)):
    if isinstance(h[X],str): h[X]=0
```

Here `isinstance` checks whether a member of a list is of some type (`str` aka `string` in this case). The list is modified in-place and without any copies.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a list comprehension, which can test and replace the string values simply and cleanly in one line. A list comprehension creates a new list by testing every element in the iterable you give it. This one tests the type of each element and replaces elements of type str with 0.

```
    >>> h = [1, 2, 5.3, '00cc', 3.2, '085d']
    >>> i = [0 if type(element) == str else element for element in h]
    >>> i
    [1, 2, 5.3, 0, 3.2, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, it is best not to use `is` to check type and should use `isinstance` instead.  I include unicode just in case but you can remove.

```
[0 if isinstance(i, (str, unicode)) else i for i in h]
```